# Android App - Get user's current location without opening the app

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application that needs to send current location of user to a server every few minutes. Is there a way to send this information in the background as I do not want the user to open the app or ask his permission to retrieve location every few minutes?

Comment: use background service to do this stuff.

Comment: actually you need a class to execute an process in second plane, it doesn´t matter if you have to send data or receive or proccess

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want some sort of background service. I suggest and [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) and then you need a way to call that service periodically. I suggest the new [JobScheduler API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html). The JobScheduler API is API 22 and up, so I would suggest using the [GCM NetworkManager](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager) api. It will actually use the native JobScheduler API when the current device is >= API 22.